# Overriding controllers in Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, controller, prestashop-1.7

Hi I want to override a controller (in /controllers/front/MyAccountController.php) I tried different things :

- In a custom module : /modules/my_module/override/controllers/front/MyAccountController.php

  ```
  class MyAccountController extends MyAccountControllerCore
  {


  /**
   * Assign template vars related to page content
   * @see FrontController::initContent()
   */
  public function initContent()
  {
      exit("test");

  }
  ```
- In /override/controllers/front/MyAccountController.php

  ```
  // SAME CODE //
  ```

I also tried with this code :

```
    class MyAccountControllerCore extends FrontController
    {


    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        exit("test");

    }
```

What is the correct wayto do it, please ?

Comment: I have the same problem. it is not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All this methods should work,

Did you check the option Disable all overrides in Advanced Parameters > Performance

[image: screenshot]

It should be to No.

You can also delete the file app/cache/prod/class_index.php to force PrestaShop to scan the override folder.

Comment: I think I just did some magic, or Prestashop is trolling me but the overrides was allowed (set to "No") then, I tried to change it to "Yes", saved, re-change to "No", saved and clear the cache, and it works ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

To override MyAccountController controller you need to extend MyAccountControllerCore class and in initContent function add parent::initContent() and clear cache it may work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).